# DevExtreme file upload - get file content in component

Tags: angular, devextreme

I want to upload a file using DevExtreme dxFileUploader and process its content in component (not using service url).

I am using Angular 8.2.2 and DevExtreme 19.1. I have tried processing the file with onValueChange event but I only get file's attributes (file name, file size etc.) not the content itself.

app.component.html:

```html
<dx-file-uploader #fileUploader (onValueChanged)="processFile($event)"
[multiple]="false" accept="*" [(value)]="value" uploadMode="useButtons">
</dx-file-uploader>
```

app.component.ts:

```js
public value: any[] = [];

processFile(e) {
   console.log(this.value); // shows only file attributes
}
```

Is there a way to get access to the file content from dxFileUploader control?

Answer (score 0):

```js
processFile(e) {
    console.log(e.value[0]);
}
```

Comment: Please, describe how the suggested code solves the problem, also try to include more details.